# SQL server connection (JDBC)

Tags: java, sql

i would like to connect the microsoft SQL server with java, using JDBC but i can't.

I have done these steps:

- download jdbc https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2137600
- extraxt a zip file
- add mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre14.jar to my eclipse IDE:  --> propeties --> java build path --> classpath --> add external JAR --> selected mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre14.jar
- in Microsoft SQL server configuration manager --> SQL server network configuration --> protocol for MCSQLSERVER --> tpc/ip --> enabled
- i created a SQL server authentication named theapplegeek

java -version:

```
openjdk version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I wrote this code:

```
package sqlConn;

import java.sql.*;

public class connessione {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Create a variable for the connection string.
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1344;databaseName=magazzino_automatica";
            String user = "theapplegeek";
            String password = "microsoftsqlservermerda";

            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password)) {
            } 
            // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}

error:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: La connessione TCP/IP all'host localhost, porta 1344 non è riuscita. Errore: "Connect timed out. Verificare le proprietà di connessione. Assicurarsi che un'istanza di SQL Server sia in esecuzione sull'host e accetti le connessioni TCP/IP alla porta. Verificare inoltre che le connessioni TCP alla porta non siano bloccate da un firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:285)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2462)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:668)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2695)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2362)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2213)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at sql/sqlConn.connessione.main(connessione.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JDBC URL, change "1344" to "1433".  Also, make sure your firewall rules don't prevent the connection.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

In SQL configuration manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols for SQL Express-> Right click on TCP/IP  you have to enable the TCP for that port. For some editions of MSSQL the TCP is disabled by default.
Also make sure the TCP is enabled for your port
Right click on TCP/Ip ->click properties->click IP addresses under IP all the value for TCP port should match to your port 1344.